# How i can access my site from other computer through internet?

Tags: web-server

I am a new web developer.
I have created my first website for a Hotel.
Hotel manager wants to see it through Internet ..but i have not created domain name for it so far.
Can you please help me on how i can make it available on Internet using web servers ip. so that other users who uses internet can access it using server ip.
If you have any document/site where i can learn the basics for this activity.

Your help is highly appreciated..
Thanks

Comment: You need to add a bunch more information here...operating system, webserver, current networking situation between your server and the user, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Umm. I'm not entirely sure what you even mean with that.

Hotel manager? Your boss or the webhotel operator? 
Why would a webhotel operator have a need to see some web page before it's installed in the hotel?

Or if I misunderstood again, just buy some 15$ webhotel package from somewhere, upload the page and use the webhotel operators test address to view it.

Setting up a private http server is quite a task for someone not familiar with networks and services. Tutorials are plenty, but it's a broad subject.